# What kinds of symbols will the linker put into an executable ELF?

Tags: c++, c, linux, linker, elf

Consider the following command:

```
g++ -Wl,--start-group main.o liba.a -Wl,--end-group -o a.out
```

Is it possible that in a.out there are some symbols defined in liba.a but not used by main.o? If yes, in what cases? Are there some tricks in writing the source code or invoking the compiler or linker to make this possible? According to my knowledge, this should not happen, but I did encounter a case like that recently.

Comment: Is this a school asignment or an interview question?

Comment: you said you encounter a case. what case ?

Comment: I compiled chromium myself and found a lot of unused symbols in the final executable ELF file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of at least three circumstances where this might happen:

1. `-Wl,--whole-archive` can be used to force `liba.a` to be included in its *entirety* rather than just the required object files.
2. `liba.a` might contain symbols that are used by the C runtime, bypassing the contents of `main.o`.  The most common cause of such symbols is C++ global or file scope objects with constructors.
3. By default the linker prunes unused code at the scale of individual *object files*; if an object file defines a bunch of symbols only some of which were used, all of them will be present regardless.  You can get around this by compiling everything that *goes into* `liba.a` with `-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections` and then giving `-Wl,--gc-sections` at link time.  With very recent GCC (I wouldn't try this with anything earlier than 4.7), compiling *everything* with `-flto` and then linking with `-fwhole-program` may also help.

Comment: If we ignore flto, I don't agree. if you link directly with `liba.a`, then that whole library gets pulled in whether you need it or not. `-la` would not pull all of it in.

Comment: @mats I can't check right now but I am 99% sure you are mistaken: -la

Comment: … `-la` and `liba.a` mean exactly the same thing to the linker as far as I know.